# Rear number plate UK laws

Tags: maintenance, car

I replaced my rear bumper number plate over the weekend and it has just been pointed out to my by a colleague that it's fallen off in the driveway at work. I'm not able to get hold of any glue or sticky pads to put it back on until I get home (20 minute drive).

The area I drive through is quite quiet and there's hardly ever a police car around, but I'm just wondering the regulations regarding this - will I be pulled over and fined for driving without it?

I can get it fixed no problem by the time I'll next need to drive, just wondering what the possible repercussions are of me driving without it.

Comment: You can also be fined for a dirty number plate...

Comment: @SolarMike Plenty of people I've seen here drive around with dirty ones, so maybe this isn't as serious not having one at all?

Comment: Or perhaps the police have better things to do... but one police doc on tv did show them stopping someone..

Comment: Personally I'd prop it in the rear window so it at least shows that you're making an effort to try and display it, then get it fixed asap. As @SteveMatthews says though, it's off-topic really as it's a legal question rather than a maintenance one

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a legal issue not a maintenance one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are stopped you will be given a vehicle defect notice which gives you seven days to rectify the fault.

I think this thread may end up being closed as it doesn't relate directly to maintenance but more to vehicle law in the UK.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't sure if this was the best place for the question, or if there was a better SE site. I debated posting on law.se for a while. Can always be moved over if there's a better site, but thanks for the answer anyway.